# Пример с WM_KILLFOCUS

Tags: c#, winapi

"Сообщение WM_KILLFOCUS отправляется окну немедленно перед тем, как оно теряет фокус клавиатуры."
Помогите, пожалуйста, с рабочим примером на C#. Необходимо отследить потерю фокуса чужого окна. Гугл не помог или я видимо неправильно запрос составляю.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `SetWindowsHookEx` + `WH_CALLWNDPROC`.
Из статьи [*Хуки в Win32*](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/baseserv/winhooks.xml#EVHAC) на RSDN:

> **`WH_CALLWNDPROC`**
>
> Windows вызывает этот хук при каждом вызове функции `SendMessage`.
>   Фильтрующей функции передается код хука, показывающий, была ли
>   произведена посылка сообщения из текущего потока, а также указатель на
>   структуру с информацией о сообщении.
>
> Структура `CWPSTRUCT` описана следующим образом:
>
> ```
> typedef struct tagCWPSTRUCT {
>     LPARAM  lParam;
>     WPARAM  wParam;
>     DWORD   message;
>     HWND    hwnd;
> } CWPSTRUCT, *PCWPSTRUCT, NEAR *NPCWPSTRUCT, FAR *LPCWPSTRUCT;
> ```
>
> Фильтры могут обработать сообщение, но не могут изменять его (хотя это
>   было возможно в Win16). Сообщение затем отсылается той функции,
>   которой и предназначалось. Этот хук использует значительное количество
>   системных ресурсов, особенно, когда он установлен с системной областью
>   видимости, поэтому используйте его только в целях отладки.